# Ajax Operations inside the WEB-INF not working

Tags: java, spring, jsf, managed-bean

I try to set values to managed bean via ajax requests. Because i am tring to load a xhtml file dynamically. My file located inside the WEB-INF directory. When I execute AJAX request with the relevant action link. Ajax Request doesn't set the value on managed bean. Why is that? Here's my code

***My view file***

```
 <h:form>


                <h:commandLink id="add" type="button" action='#{userBean.setPath("add")}' class="btn btn-info">Add User

                    <f:ajax execute="add" render="userPage"/>

                </h:commandLink>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit User</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View Profile</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Activity Records</button>

            </h:form>
               <div>
                    <h:panelGroup id="userPage">
                        <ui:include src="#{userBean.path}" />
                         </h:panelGroup>
                </div>
```

***Managed Bean file***

```
@ManagedBean
public class UserBean {
    private String path;

    public UserBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        path = "/WEB-INF/user_management/intro.xhtml";
    }

    public String getPath() {
          System.out.println("get");
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        System.out.println("set");
        this.path = "/WEB-INF/dashboard.xhtml";
    }
}
```

Comment: You know debug? Try putting a breakpoint set Path method to track the path of the request.

Comment: will breakpoint work to ajax requests?

Comment: No. My idea is to treat this problem. You need to understand what is happening. I recommend you also use a try catch in the method.

Comment: No even possible that. Because the ajax requests doesn't touch the method :(

Comment: Try using @ViewScoped on your managedbean